# PyQt5 QLabel text not changing?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

Consider this minimal code snippet :

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication,QWidget,QLabel

app=QApplication([])
w=QWidget()
l=QLabel(w)
l.setText("Ready")
w.show()

def load():
    l.setText('Loading...')
    some_function()
    l.setText('Loaded')

load()
```

The desired output here is that the `QLabel` text should change to 'Loading...' first and then after some_function() finishes it's task, it should change to 'Loaded'

**But** that isn't how it's working. The 'Loading...' text **never** appears. It jumps straight from 'Ready' to 'Loaded' after the completion of some_function(). Why is that happening?

Comment: 1) add `from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer` 2) remove `sleep(3)`, 3) change `l.setText('Bye')` to `QTimer.singleShot(3 * 1000, lambda: l.setText('Bye'))`

Comment: Actually, in my application there is some function instead of sleep(sec). I just wrote that here for an example, my bad. Have made the appropriate changes to the post.

Comment: then add `import threading`, change `some_function()` to `threading.Thread(target= some_function, daemon=True).start()`

Comment: But that will just create a parallel task and the current process control will shift to setText('Loaded') immediately. I don't think it would work.
EDIT : Not working, as anticipated.

Comment: see https://gist.github.com/eyllanesc/14123c70b1dfc4941bdf1144cf6580cd

Comment: I've never dealt with pyqtSignal(), emit() and pyqtSlot decorator. Would be very nice of you if you could comment those portions. Please ? _/'|'\_

Comment: read the docs: https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html . These elements are the fundamental part of Qt. Read also https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html